# Bash don't capture ssh errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I run

```
mapfile -t array_files < <(ssh -i key user@host "find / -name search -type f")
```

and print the results in $?, I receive 0 even when the command fail.

Comment: the result of find... this command works when the user and host is correct, but when fail I receive 0 in $?

Comment: `$?` contains the exit status of `mapfile`, not `ssh`. Also, what do you mean by "fail"? `find` doesn't consider it failure to find 0 files.

Comment: If you want to know if it found anything, check the length of `$array_files`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bash.

```
# disable job control and enable lastpipe to run mapfile in current environment
set +m; shopt -s lastpipe

# feed array_files with the output of your ssh/find command
ssh ... | mapfile -t array_files

# returncode of first command in pipe (here ssh)
echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"

# content of array array_files
declare -p array_files
```

In a script job control is disabled by default.