# Bash Script Not Concatenating String as Intended

Tags: bash, shell

**Goal**

I want to take a line break separated file (path in `$2`), check the path exists and add it to `folderList`.

**Current Code**

I am not yet checking for file path correctness as I can't get concatenation to work.

```
folderList=""

cat $2 | while read line
do
   folderList="$folderList;$line"
   echo $line #echos the right content
done

echo $folderList
```

The output shoes that it echos `line` correctly but `folderList` is simply an empty line (not showing on Stack Overflow formatting).

```
foo
bar
```

**Working Code Without File Path Checking**

```
folderList="$(tr '\n' ';' < $2)"
```

Comment: Don't use pipeline otherwise your changes are being made in a subshell. Use `done < "$2"`

Comment: See: [Can't use a variable out of while and pipe in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6572411/3776858) and [How to pipe input to a Bash while loop and preserve variables after loop ends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19570413/3776858)

Comment: Those comments hit the nail on the head and fixed it. Happy to have it closed for duplication. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This might help, too: [Bash don't capture ssh errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57401200/3776858)